# Android camera Intent doesn't return in RESULT_OK case

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I'm trying to stand up a simple Android app that uses a camera via Intents.  The code is pretty much straight from the [Android documentation here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#manifest), but it isn't working for me.

The camera app opens as expected after the call to startActivityForResult(), but it never returns after I've taken a picture (?!).  Specifically, it doesn't return after I take a photo and pick the accept icon (check mark on Galaxy Nexus).  But it does return after I pick the the cancel icon ('X' on the same phone).

Here's the code (note, I'm working from a Fragment, not an Activity):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);

    final Button btnCamera = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.cameraid);

    View.OnClickListener handler = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v == btnCamera) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                // create a file to save the image
                File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImages");
                imagesFolder.mkdirs();
                File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image_001.jpg");
                Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);

                // start the image capture Intent
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }
    }
    btnCamera.setOnClickListener(handler);
}
```

and

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image saved to:\n" +
                     data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
        } else {
            // Image capture failed, advise user
        }
    }
```

What do I need to change to make this work?  Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Oops, it worked when I added the manifest lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

I mistakenly thought these lines were not necessary if your app relies on an external camera app.  But I was wrong about that!  Thanks.